# Geometry, help with triangles

Tags: geometry

How can I show using the appropriate axioms of euclidean geometry that if two triangles have there corresponding angles equal, then there corresponding sides are scaled up versions of each other.

Comment: I wrote down everything I could think of, is there somthing else your looking for?

Comment: Do you know which axioms to use? Have you tried applying them to two triangles with corresponding equal angles...? Just that you have tried to solve the problem in some fashion. This is just friendly advice. Regards

Comment: Yes I have tried this

Comment: @sam2946 People on SE usually like to see that you put some effort into trying to answer your question, and the more effort you show the more willing are the people to answer it.

Comment: When I was High School, many years ago, they assumed the ratios were rational, along with a comment that this was not always correct. Euclid famously does this much better. So, how are High School students taught today.